# From before, from aforementioned

Tags: british-english, adverbs

Can *before* and *aforementioned* be used in a similar way to *above*?

Context: Say I'm writing a report, and would like to reference an earlier bit. If that earlier bit is in close proximity or follows immediately before, I might use "From *above*, we can see...". In this case, can I use "From *before*/*aforementioned*", especially if that earlier bit is at a certain distance away? Other examples are "As seen from *above*/*before*, ...", "... when applying [technical term], from *before*." -- [technical term] defined above.

I know that this isn't common and comes off as rather technical, I'm alright with that. My concern is whether using it as such is grammatically correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Melvin. 'From aforementioned' is a far worse version of 'From previous', which is itself non-standard. 'From earlier' might work, but I'd use, for example, 'from the arguments/results in section 3', which helps the reader check back anyway.

Comment: I don't understand. "Aforementioned" is an adjective (and possibly a pronoun, I suppose, if the noun is understood) referring to something that was already talked about within the same discourse. "Above" and "before" are either prepositions or adverbs ("before" can also be an conjunction) that refer to an aspect of a relationship (when/where something is/was in relation to another). By what definitions do you believe they are interchangeable?

Comment: In legal texts, aforementioned is used all the time. That said, don't use from like that. In the aforementioned case, blah blah blah. In the ***foregoing example***, blah blah blah. The foregoing example shows A, B and C.

Answer (score -1):

"Per the aforementioned..." if you really want to use the word aforementioned, I would avoid it and say something like "From the "definition" in [section number] we see that..." or whatever the particular item is that you're referencing, if it's the next paragraph then "As we see above..." is highly appropriate.